# Refresh a treeview and expand last selected node

Tags: c#, treeview

In my application i copy a certain pdf file to the selected node, after this i want the treeview to refresh and show me the added file.

The refresh is working but it won't expand the last selected node.

How can i do a refresh but still keep the last selected node expanded, so the user can see that the pdf file is added to the folder.

[image]

Comment: Don't 'refresh' it, just add the node.  If refreshing is really necessary (hard to see why) then you'll need to find the node back yourself so you can call its Expand() method.  You can leave breadcrumbs with the Name property.

Answer (score 4):

The AfterSelect on the TreeView have a parameter TreeViewEventArgs e. e.Node will return the selected node. eg:

```
e.Node.Expand();
```

or

```
e.Node.ExpandAll();
```

Should you wish to expand all the nodes in the treeview. You can use the same method to expand the

I assume that you know which node you have copied it too. Use the same method to expand the node you've copied too.